# Symfony2 - UniqueEntity no action

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine, entity

I have an entity named Test with two fields: id and name.
I would like to have the name as unique.

What I did:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

...

/**
 * Company\AppBundle\Entity\Test
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="test")
 * @UniqueEntity("name")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Company\AppBundle\Entity\TestRepository")
 * 
 */
class Test
{

....

/**
 * @var string$name
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=200, nullable=false, unique=true)
 */
private $name;

....
```

In my controller, I am using:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
   ....
```

But the validation goes through. Am I missing something?

Comment: is `Test` entity the main entity of the form, or is it embedded into the form you're trying to validate?

Comment: @DonCallisto, the test entity is the main entity of the form!

Comment: is this a typo ```/**
 * @var integer $test
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="test", type="string", length=200, nullable=false, unique=true)
 */
private $test;``` ?

Comment: Can you attach whole controller action and form type? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique annotation is for doctrine, it passes it to the database level and the error gets thrown from there. It will not know that the entity exists until you try to save it. To do the checks in php you have to query for the unique attribute yourself and check if it exists...

Comment: Hi Joe. I agree with you but when trying to add a duplicate value, I am getting the `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry "aaaa" for key "name"`

Comment: Yes exactly, the error is thrown on the database level, below the php. If you want to check before the actual error is thrown you have to do a manual query.

Comment: Hi Joe, are you sure? I think that the query for uniqueness is made automatically and internally when executing the line $form->isValid() and Symfony "magic" tests the uniqueness (checking if there is a integrity violation I suppose). So I think you haven't to do that query manually.

Comment: I spent a year thinking whether or not I was sure, yes I think I am sure. Doing that check is impossible without a query, doctrine does not do that query automatically. There is no way it can internally know that this key is unique or not before querying first..